# How can I rotate a Rectangle?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to rotate a `Rectangle` (the Java class) created with

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
```

I cannot appear to find anything in the API for it. If I google "Java rotate a rectangle", then I can only find threads telling me how to *draw* it rotated, and not just rotate the object.

Comment: `AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle).createTransformedShape(rect)` should return a `Shape` representing the rotated rectangle?

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't seem to find that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle).createTransformedShape(rect)` creates a Shape representing the rotated rectangle.  (It can't return another `Rectangle` because `Rectangle` expects to just be straight along the x/y axes.)

Comment: I'm mainly just using this for collision, so as long as I can use shape.intersects(otherShape), then I should be fine :).